# Hadoop Customize Input Distribution on Nodes

Tags: networking, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am working on Hadoop. Goal is to detect certain key words into network traffic (network packets). I am using a Hadoop cluster of 4 nodes. I want each node to perform operations on different types of packets (eg. TCP, SMTP). How do I distribute the packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify packets according to tcp-ip protocols you can use **pcap library (jnetpcap)** which has function **PcapPacket.hasHeader(protocol instance)** 
where protocol object should be instantiated before calling hasHeader function
e.g. 
Tcp tcp = new Tcp(); 
Udp udp = new Udp(); 
PcapPacket packet = //got from somewhere 
if(packet.hasHeader(tcp){ 
      //packet is tcp 
       key= tcp 
} 
else if(packet.hasHeader(udp)){ 
       //packet is udp 
       key = udp 
}

This way you can **set the key as protocol and value as packet's data** of (key, value) pair to be given to reducer of hadoop's MapReduce. 
Then **all (key,value) pairs having same key will go to one reducer.**